# file transfer code python

Tags: python

I found the code here: [Send a file through sockets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382045/send-a-file-through-sockets-in-python) (the selected answer)

But I will jut post it here again..

```
server.py
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost",9999))
s.listen(10) 
while True:
    sc, address = s.accept()

    print address
    i=1
    f = open('file_'+ str(i)+".txt",'wb') #open in binary
    i=i+1
    while (True):       
        l = sc.recv(1024)
        while (l):
            print l #<--- i can see the data here
            f.write(l) #<--- here is the issue.. the file is blank
            l = sc.recv(1024)
    f.close()

    sc.close()

s.close()



client.py

import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost",9999))
f=open ("test.txt", "rb") 
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    print l
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
s.close()
```

On server code, the print l line prints the file contents..so that means that content is being transferred..
but then the file is empty??

what am i missing?
thanks

Comment: Are your indents correct? I don't see how it ever breaks out of your middle ``while True`` even when it's read all the data from the client socket it's stuck in that loop.

Comment: @sotapme: Yeah. i feel that so. I copied over the code from  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382045/send-a-file-through-sockets-in-python (the selected answer) I am figuring out the right indents. Please let me know incase you figured it out. Thanks

Comment: To my mind that middle ``while True`` is unnecessary, surely when you run the code it prints blanks lines forever when it's copied the file across.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably trying to inspect the file while the program is running. The file is being buffered, so you likely won't see any output in it until the `f.close()` line is executed, or until a large amount of data is written. Add a call to `f.flush()` after the `f.write(l)` line to see output in real time. Note that it will hurt performance somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

Well that server code didn't work anyway, I've modified it to get it working.

The file was empty because it was stuck in the `while True` and never got around to closing the file.

Also `i=1` was inside the loop so it was always writing to the same file.

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost",9999))
s.listen(10)
i=1
while True:
    print "WILL accept"
    sc, address = s.accept()
    print "DID  accept"

    print address
    f = open('file_'+ str(i)+".txt",'wb') #open in binary
    i += 1
    l = sc.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        f.write(l) #<--- here is the issue.. the file is blank
        l = sc.recv(1024)
    f.close()

    sc.close()

print "Server DONE"
s.close()
```