# send and receive a file in python sockets

Tags: python, sockets

This has for the most part been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382045/send-a-file-through-sockets-in-python)
I have been trying to modify the server (to send) and client (to receive) feedback from the server upon receipt of the entire file.

below is the client server code; as it is presently both client and server hang. ie. indefintely go into "busy" state (both client and server do nothing, until ctrl-c on the server reports failure here "l = sc.recv(1024)" and ctrl-c on the  client reports failure here "reply =s.recv(1024)")

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost",3000))
s.listen(10)
i=1
while True:
    sc, address = s.accept()
    print address
    f = open('tranmit.jpg",'wb') #open in binary
    l = 1
    while(l):
        l = sc.recv(1024)
        while (l):
            f.write(l)
            l = sc.recv(1024)
        f.close()
        sc.send("received") # Would like to send back a response

    sc.close()

s.close()
------------------------------------------------------------
#client
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost",3000))
f=open ("tranmit.jpg", "rb") 
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
reply =s.recv(1024) # Feedback: would like the receive feedback from the server.
print reply
s.close()
```

The code works fine without the feedback lines added in (as in the link above), does anyone have an idea on how to keep this working with the feedback as well?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client must indicate, somehow, that the entire file has been sent. As it stands, your server has no way of knowing when the client's send operations are complete.

One solution is to call `socket.shutdown` after all transmissions are complete. Here is a new version of your client program. No changers were required to your server program.

```
#client
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost",3000))
f=open ("tranmit.jpg", "rb")
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
reply =s.recv(1024) # Feedback: would like the receive feedback from the server.
print reply
s.close()
```

Comment: I thought I may seek your assistance something similar to this again, so it works fine with string/text like response from the server, however "reply =s.recv(1024)" client code seems to hang indefinitely when you introduce a function call on the server end, especially if the function takes over 60s to run... any ideas? Whereas the server completes running the function call and returns a result, this result never gets to the client process. thanks in advance

Comment: That sounds like a whole new question. Following the guidelines in [ask] and [mcve], please post a new question on Stack Overflow.